# Sorting user reputation by questions rep or answers rep

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation, user-interface

Is there any way to sort the user list by reputation earned through questions only? (Or through answers only?)

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: You could probably tackle this through the Data Explorer; however it should be hard---if not outright impossible---to circumvent reputation caps. So what you could probably do, relatively easily, is sort users by the number of upvotes they received on their questions or answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature of the site that allows this.

However the Data Explorer allows to retrieve this information.

Here is a (somewhat rough) [query for questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/125157/total-reputation-from-questions); it is based on the score, not up and downvotes separately.

Comment: Also related: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/158958/votes-most-upvoted-users which sorts user by average on how many votes they received on an average post (which is why Andre and Brian are missing).